# CVCalendar View Dates extend beyond calendar view

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am trying to make my CVCalendar view compatible with screen rotations where if the device is an iphone and in landscape the view will switch to weekView, and if anything else it will be in monthView. Here is my Code:

```
 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)


    let isPhone: Bool = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    let isLandscape: Bool = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: {
        _ in


         if isLandscape && isPhone {

            self.calendarView.changeMode(.weekView)


        } else {

            self.calendarView.changeMode(.monthView)
        }
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly for transition to .weekView. However when transitioning back to .monthView on the iphone 6,7 and plus' the calendar view dates extend beyond the calendarView.

[image: example of calendarView not fitting view properly]